# Problems getting ASPNetSpell to work on a multiline text box

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an ASPNetSpell:SpellTextBox control on my page and if I type a simple line of text it appears to work fine, however if I have a hard return in the text box and keep typing, the cursor is jumped around the text box every time I pause typing and the spell checker kicks in.  Consequently I am getting words appearing in the middle of other words and more curiously am getting html tags appearing in the text.  I don't get this problem when using their demo on their website, but am getting it on my set up.

Anyone got any clues ?

Thanks

Rab

Comment: Rab, you're going to need to show some code so we can see how it is "on your set up", without that, there's no way of knowing. Any other js events tied to that TextBox?

Comment: I have downloaded the code again from the website and my problems have stopped.  I can only assume a dodgy download or a bug had crept in to their code that was resolved in the interim. The control now works perfectly and does a great job - we shall deffinitely be purchasing it!

Comment: For what its worth, we bought this control back in May and its working really well. We have recently found a slight bug with regards to copying and pasting between controls using right mouse context menus, but the company were quick to respond and produced a solution within a couple of days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is now resolved.

1. Download the latest release from http://www.aspnetspell.com/ASPNetSpell_Packages
2. Update Bin/ASPNetSpell.dll
3. Update the ~/ASPNetSpellInclude folder
4. Clear your browser cache.